# ANT compile is working fine but ANT run not working build failed "failed to create task or type testng"

Tags: ant

Below is my Build.xml file. when i compile my project it shows Build Success but when i run it then Build Failed "failed to create task or type testng" Cause: the name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="projectName" default="clean" basedir="C:\Users\saad bin usman\workspace\testNG"> <!-- dot indicates that basedir is pointing towards project root directory -->

 <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
 <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}" />
 <property name="ws.jars" value="D:\jars" />
 <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
 <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
 <property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

 <echo> value of base dir = ${basedir} </echo>

 <!-- properties for copying the results -->
 <tstamp>
 <format property="year" pattern="yyyy" />
 <format property="DSTAMP" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
 <format property="TSTAMP" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
 <format property="dateversion" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm:ss" />
 <format property="time.stamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss aa_"/>
 </tstamp>

 <property name="testng.report.dir" value="${ws.home}/testngReports/${time.stamp}"/>
 <property name="testngXslt.report.dir" value="${ws.home}/testngXsltReports/${time.stamp}"/>

 <!-- ====== For setting the classpath ==== -->
 <target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
 <path id="classpath_jars">
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes = "*.jar"/>
 </path>
 <pathconvert pathsep=":"
 property="test.classpath"
 refid="classpath_jars" />

 </target>

 <!-- ============ Initializing other stuff =========== -->
 <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
 <tstamp>
 <format property="start.time" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy (HH-mm-ss)"/>
 </tstamp>
 <condition property="ANT"
 value="$(env.ANT_HOME)/bin/ant.bat"
 else="$(env.ANT_HOME)/bin/ant">
 <!-- os family="windows" /-->
 <os family="mac" />
 </condition>



 <!--
 <!- use direct path for classpath if you don't prefer to use 'lib' directory: classpath="/Users/yash/Documents/Jar Files/testng-6.8.jar" ->
 <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
 <classpath>
 <pathelement location="./lib/testng.jar"/>
 </classpath>
 </taskdef>
 -->

 </target>

 <target name="all">
 </target>

 <!-- cleaning the destination folders -->
 <target name="clean">
 <echo message="deleting existing build directory"/>
 <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
 </target>

 <!-- target for compiling the java files -->
 <target name="compile" depends="init, clean">
 <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
 <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
 </delete>
 <echo message="making directory....."/>
 <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
 <echo message="classpath-------: ${test.classpath}"/>
 <echo message="compiling....."/>
 <javac
 debug="true"
 destdir="${test.dest}"
 srcdir="${test.src}"
 classpath="${test.classpath}"
 includeantruntime="true"/>
 </target>

 <!-- build -->
 <target name="build" depends="init">
 </target>

 <!-- ========== Test executions & Generating reports using Testng utility for multiple suites ============== -->
 <!-- run -->


<target name="run" depends="compile">

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="D:\saad bin usman\saad's doc\softwares\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.9.8.201510130443\lib\*.jar" />

    <testng classpath="classpath.test" suitename="smsweb" outputDir="test-output" >
        <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>


    </target>

 <target name="testngReportCopyAndReportParser">
 <!-- Copy to TestNG report directory-->
 <mkdir dir="${testngDir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestNG report directory -->
 <copy todir="${testngDir}">
 <fileset dir="test-output"/>
 </copy> <!-- end of Testng Report -->
 </target>

 <!-- ========== Test executions & Generating reports using Testng XSLT utility for multiple suites ============== -->
 <!-- run -->
 <target name="runAsTestngXslt" depends="compile">

 <!--suite 1 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer" value="CopyRegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="CopyRegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="webSuites/CopyRegressionCustomer.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngXsltReportCopy">
 <param name="testngXsltDir" value="${testngXslt.report.dir}${suite.web.CopyRegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 <!--suite 2 begin -->
 <property name="suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer" value="Copy2RegressionCustomer" />
 <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="Copy2RegressionCustomer" outputDir="test-output" >
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="webSuites/Copy2RegressionCustomer.xml" />
 </testng>
 <antcall target="testngXsltReportCopy">
 <param name="testngXsltDir" value="${testngXslt.report.dir}${suite.web.Copy2RegressionCustomer}"/>
 </antcall> 

 </target>

 <target name="testngXsltReportCopyAndReportParser">
 <!-- Copy to TestNG report directory-->
 <mkdir dir="${testngXsltDir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestngXslt report folder -->
 <xslt in="${ws.home}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
 out="${testngXsltDir}/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

 <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${testngXsltDir}" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" />
 </xslt> <!-- end of TestngXslt Report -->
 </target>

 <path id="test.c">
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar">
 <include name="mail.jar"/>
 <include name="activation-1.0.2.jar"/>
 </fileset>
 </path>

 <!-- ========== Generating reports using Testng XSLT utility for single suite only ============== -->
 <target name="report" depends="run">
 <!-- TestngXslt report -->
 <mkdir dir="${testngXslt.report.dir}">
 </mkdir>

 <!-- to copy previous suite result to TestngXslt report folder -->
 <xslt in="${ws.home}/test-output/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
 out="${testngXslt.report.dir}/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

 <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${testngXslt.report.dir}" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" expression="true" />
 <param name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" />
 </xslt> <!-- end of TestngXslt Report -->
 </target>

 <target name="RunAndViewReport" depends="report">
 <exec executable="${browser}" spawn="yes">
 <arg line="'file:///${testngXslt.report.dir}/index.html'" />
 </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="sendMail" depends="RunAndViewReport">
 <zip destfile="${testngXslt.report.dir}/Report.zip" basedir="${testngXslt.report.dir}"/>
 <mail mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="465" subject="Notification of TESTNG build result" ssl="false" user="automationmoolya@gmail.com" password="moolya@universe">
 <from address="automationmoolya@gmail.com"/>
 <to address="yagnesh@moolya.com"/>
 <message>The build has finished. A details report of this build is attached</message>
 <attachments>
 <fileset dir="testngXslt.report.dir">
 <include name="**/*.zip"/>
 </fileset>
 </attachments>
 </mail>
 </target>

 <target name="install-jars" description="Install ANT optional jars">
 <get dest="${ws.home}/lib/mail.jar" src="file:///${ws.home}/lib/mail.jar"/>
 <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar">
 <include name="mail.jar"/>
 <include name="activation-1.0.2.jar"/>
 </fileset>
 </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Problem Resolved with 
<testng classpath="D:\jars\testng-6.8.5.jar"

Answer (score 0):

use run like below

```
     <!-- run -->
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}"> 
        <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `taskdef` is nested inside the task you're trying to use. That's now how it works. Define the task first, then run it.

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/full/path/to/testng.jar" />

<testng classpathref="classpath.test" suitename="smsweb" outputDir="test-output" >
    <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml" />
</testng>
```

Comment: Is your classpath to testng.jar correct? In your example, which I copied for my answer, you have the path `/full/path/to/testng.jar` which is clearly not a real path. I assumed you just didn't want to show your directory names online, but if this is actually in your script, it will need to be changed to the real path of the testng jar file.

Comment: brother i replace it with my testNG Jars. console showing error on <Testng /> line. i also replace classpath.test with test.classpath means with property of classpath but its not working. wait i also update above my build.xml with your code.